# How to draw ROC graph on predictions of binary class python project, sentiment analysis

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on judiciary cases to predict the result about conviction nd acquittal. There are two classes of it. I have preprocessed the data and trained many models as well such as SVM, NB, RF, DT, LR and KNN. Now I want to draw ROC graph for each model separately. I have tried many odes but facing same problem.

My code:

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
# calculate the fpr and tpr for all thresholds of the classification
probs = rfc.predict_proba(x_testcv)
preds = probs[:,1]
fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, preds)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

# method I: plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()

# method II: ggplot
from ggplot import *
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fpr = fpr, tpr = tpr))
ggplot(df, aes(x = 'fpr', y = 'tpr')) + geom_line() + geom_abline(linetype = 'dashed')
```

The Error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9516/749508573.py in <module>
      3 probs = rfc.predict_proba(x_testcv)
      4 preds = probs[:,1]
----> 5 fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, preds)
      6 roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
      7 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    911 
    912     """
--> 913     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
    914         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    915 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    689     if not (y_type == "binary" or
    690             (y_type == "multiclass" and pos_label is not None)):
--> 691         raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    692 
    693     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)

ValueError: unknown format is not supported
```